# Change text every 30 percent in progress bar c#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, progress-bar

i wanted to make every 30 percent in progress bar, the text changes.

What i wanted to do is, when the progress bar hit 25 percent, the text changes and it stop for a second, and it goes back to 50, and the text changes again, it keep going until it hit 100 percent.

Here is my code:

```
        public WelcomeScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _timer.Interval = 2000;
            label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void WelcomeScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var percentComplete = e.ProgressPercentage;
            var userState = (string)e.UserState;

            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            progressBar1.Value = 100;
            progressBar1.Step = 25;

            if (progressBar1.Step <= 25)
            {
                label1.Text = "Preparing Setup";
            }

            else if (progressBar1.Step <= 50)
            {
                label1.Text = "Preparing Application";
            }

            else if (progressBar1.Step <= 75)
            {
                label1.Text = "Preparing Database";
            }

            else if (progressBar1.Step <= 100)
            {
                label1.Text = "Preparing Contents";
            }

            else
            {
                label1.Text = "Launch Application";
            }
        }

        void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

            currentWorker.ReportProgress(0, "Preparing Setup");
            currentWorker.ReportProgress(25, "Preparing Application");
            currentWorker.ReportProgress(50, "Preparing Database");
            currentWorker.ReportProgress(75, "Preparing Contents");
            currentWorker.ReportProgress(100, "Launch Application");
        }

        void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Enabled = false;

            this.Hide();

            _login.ShowDialog();

            this.Close();
        }
```

When the progress bar hit 100 percent, i order the application to wait until 2 seconds before show another form after the text changes to "Launch Application".

Comment: So why are you checking what the value of `progressBar1.Step` is? Why are you using that at all? Just set the `Value` equal to the `percentComplete`?

Comment: What i wanted to do is, when the progress bar hit 25 percent, the text changes and it stop for a second, and it goes back to 50, and the text changes again, it keep going until it hit 100 percent sir. That's why i set the value of `progressBar1.Step`, but the text keep stay on `Preparing Setup`

Comment: You don't need to use that property. Let the BackgroundWorker dictate the value of the progress bar is.

Comment: So, what i must do sir in order to changes the text every value of `progressBar.Step` hit 25 percent and 50 percent and so on? I wanted to show that text.

Answer (score 1):

All the code in your `WelcomeScreen_Load` will block the UI thread until it is complete. This means that no matter what you do to your progress bar, it will never show it's changes until it is complete (which it will "jump" to the last settings).

You will want to look into [`Background Workers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). These let you do your code async, and report back every-so-often with what the current state is (ie: the percent complete).

So, a really short example:

```
private void WelcomeScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var percentComplete = e.ProgressPercentage;
    var userState = (string)e.UserState;

    //do something with these values, like moving your progress bar
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Value = percentComplete;
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something when the worker completes, like start your timer
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // do the "work" for the background worker

    var currentWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    currentWorker.ReportProgress(0, "Just Starting");

    // do your first task
    currentWorker.ReportProgress(25, "Finish First Task");

    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you sir gunr2171, i already tried your code, but the progress bar keep continue and the text is not changing at all. I put the text in the worker_ProgressChanged. While i put in the worker_DoWork, it gave me the error

Comment: @Kaoru, Please update your post to show exactly what you have done. And you need to put your logic in `worker_DoWork`. Remember that you cannot manipulate a progress bar inside `worker_DoWork`, you will get a cross thread exception. That is why there is `worker_ProgressChanged`.

Comment: edited the code sir, please refer to the question again. Thank you